# Transform directory structure xml into html list of links xslt

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I have a directory listing xml file, automatically generated by http://code.google.com/p/xml-dir-listing/ and it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <directory name="rootdir" size="256" lastModified="1408535531000" date="20140820T145211" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir" sort="name" reverse="true">
        <directory name="20140819" size="256" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819">
            <directory name="file1" size="4096" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file1" />
            <directory name="file2" size="4096" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file2" /></directory>
        <directory name="20140818" size="256" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818">
            <directory name="file1" size="4096" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file1" />
            <directory name="file2" size="4096" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file2" /></directory>
    </directory>
```

And I need an xslt transformation to get home.html file like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>Heading</h1>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/rootdir/20140819/file1/index.html">rootdir/20140819/file1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/rootdir/20140819/file2/index.html">rootdir/20140819/file2</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/rootdir/20140818/file1/index.html">rootdir/20140818/file1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/rootdir/20140818/file2/index.html">rootdir/20140818/file2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>        
    <body>
</html>
```

I need it so every time I run the transformation my list would be updated with new directories. I believe that it could be really easy task, but I'm totally new to xslt and even though I spent decent amount of time reading about it, it's still not intuitive to me at all. Please, help.

**Edit:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<directory name="rootdir" size="256" lastModified="1408603833000" date="20140821T095033" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir" sort="name" reverse="true">
<directory name="20140819" size="256" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819">
<directory name="file1" size="4096" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file1">
<directory name="test" size="4096" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file1/test"/>
<file name="index.html" size="676" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file1/index.html"/>
</directory>
<directory name="file2" size="4096" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file2">
<directory name="test" size="256" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file2/test"/>
<file name="index.html" size="676" lastModified="1408526538000" date="20140820T122218" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140819/file2/index.html"/>
</directory>
</directory>
<directory name="20140818" size="256" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818">
<directory name="file1" size="4096" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file1">
<directory name="test" size="256" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file1/test"/>
<file name="index.html" size="676" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file1/index.html"/>
</directory>
<directory name="file2" size="4096" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file2">
<directory name="test" size="256" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file2/test"/>
<file name="index.html" size="676" lastModified="1408526552000" date="20140820T122232" absolutePath="/path/to/rootdir/20140818/file2/index.html"/>
</directory>
</directory>
</directory>
```

Here's the xml output with index.html included

Comment: Your output contains a reference to `index.html` but that file name does not occur in the input XML. Should the input xml have a `file` element present too?

Comment: yes, it can be present, I added lower walking depth, I will update the xml output right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with have a template that matches the document node where you can output the containing html elements, like so: (I've cut out some html for brevity)

```
<xsl:template match="/">
     <ul>
         <xsl:apply-templates />
     </ul>        
</xsl:template>
```

Your main problem is with concatenating the list of directory names into one long string for when the file information is output. One way to achieve this is to pass the directory name from parent to child by means of a parameter. You would have a template matching `directory` where you then concatenate onto the current path parameter and pass this to templates matching any child element.

```
<xsl:template match="directory">
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <xsl:apply-templates>
        <xsl:with-param name="path" select="concat($path, '/', @name)" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

You could then use the same parameter in a template matching `file`

```
<xsl:template match="file">
    <xsl:param name="path" />
    <li>
        <a href="{concat($path, '/', @name)}"><xsl:value-of select="$path" /></a>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="directory">
        <xsl:param name="path" />
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="path" select="concat($path, '/', @name)" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="file">
        <xsl:param name="path" />
        <li>
            <a href="{concat($path, '/', @name)}"><xsl:value-of select="$path" /></a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <ul>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </ul>        
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```